# Disable keyboard navigation from product detail page?

Tags: magento2, product-view, tabs

I want to disable keyboard navigation of tabs from product details page which is on below gallery with tabs Details, Reviews & custom tab.
You can check below link for the tabs 
http://newsmartwave.net/magento2/porto/demo14_en/catalog/product/view/id/2383/s/white-shirt-27/

Below is my details.phtml

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
<?php
    $porto_helper = $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Data');
    $_helper = $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Customtabs');
    $product_config = $porto_helper->getConfig('porto_settings/product');
    $static_block_tab = $product_config['custom_block_next_tab'];
    $custom_block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block');
    if($custom_block) {
        $custom_block->setBlockId($static_block_tab);
    }
    $tab_style = "";
    if(isset($product_config['tab_style']) && $product_config['tab_style'])
        $tab_style = $product_config['tab_style'];
?>
    <?php if($product_config['tab_full_background']):?>
    <div class="move-product-tab">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="<?php if($custom_block && $static_block_tab):?>col-sm-9<?php else:?>col-sm-12<?php endif;?>">
    <?php endif;?>
                <div class="product info detailed <?php echo $tab_style; ?>">
                <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
                <?php if(!$tab_style || $tab_style != "sticky"): ?>
                    <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
                        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                            <?php
                            $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                            if (!trim($html)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                            $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                            ?>
                            <div class="data item title"
                                 aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title"
                                 data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>">
                                <a class="data switch"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   data-toggle="switch"
                                   href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                                   id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php
                        if($custom_cms_tabs = $_helper->getCustomTabs($block->getProduct())) {
                            $i = 1;
                            foreach($custom_cms_tabs as $_item) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="data item title"
                                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i;?>-title"
                                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i;?>">
                                    <a class="data switch"
                                       tabindex="-1"
                                       data-toggle="switch"
                                       href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i; ?>"
                                       id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i;?>-title">
                                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item['tab_title']; ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i; ?>" data-role="content">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item['tab_content']; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php elseif($tab_style && $tab_style == "sticky"): ?>
                    <div class="product data items">
                        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                            <?php
                            $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                            if (!trim($html)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                            $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                            $alias = str_replace(".","_",$alias);
                            ?>
                            <div class="data item title">
                                <a class="data switch" href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php
                        if($custom_cms_tabs = $_helper->getCustomTabs($block->getProduct())) {
                            $i = 1;
                            foreach($custom_cms_tabs as $_item) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="data item title">
                                    <a class="data switch" href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i; ?>">
                                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item['tab_title']; ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                            <?php
                            $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                            if (!trim($html)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                            $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                            $alias = str_replace(".","_",$alias);
                            ?>
                            <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php
                        if($custom_cms_tabs = $_helper->getCustomTabs($block->getProduct())) {
                            $i = 1;
                            foreach($custom_cms_tabs as $_item) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "custom-".$i; ?>">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item['tab_content']; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    require([
                        'jquery'
                    ], function ($) {
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            <?php if($tab_style && $tab_style == "vertical"): ?>
                            $(".product.info.detailed.vertical .product.data.items .data.item.title").off("classadded").on("classadded",function(){
                                $(this).parent().css("min-height",$(this).next().outerHeight()+"px");
                            });
                            <?php elseif($tab_style && $tab_style == "sticky"): ?>
                            var sticky_tabs;
                            var is_sticky = false;
                            $(window).scroll(function(){
                                if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(".product.info.detailed").offset().top-50){
                                    if(!is_sticky){
                                        $(".product.info.detailed.sticky").before('<div class="product-tabs-container"><div class="container"></div></div>');
                                        $(".product.info.detailed.sticky .product.data.items > .item.title").each(function(){
                                            $(".product-tabs-container > .container").append($(this).clone().detach());
                                        });
                                        $(".product-tabs-container .item.title > a").off("click").on("click", function(){
                                            $($(this).attr("href")).scrollToMe();
                                            return false;
                                        });
                                        <?php if ($porto_helper->getConfig('porto_settings/header/sticky_header')): ?>
                                        $(".product-tabs-container").addClass("has-sticky-header");
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if ($porto_helper->getConfig('porto_settings/header/mobile_sticky_header')): ?>
                                        $(".product-tabs-container").addClass("has-mobile-sticky-header");
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        is_sticky = true;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $(".product-tabs-container").remove();
                                    is_sticky = false;
                                }
                            });
                          /*  $(".product.info.detailed.sticky .product.data.items > .item.title > a").off("click").on("click", function(){
                                $($(this).attr("href")).scrollToMe();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $(".product-reviews-summary .reviews-actions a.action.view").off("click").on("click", function(){
                                $("#reviews").scrollToMe();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $(".product-reviews-summary .reviews-actions a.action.add").off("click").on("click", function(){
                                $("#review-form").scrollToMe();
                                return false;
                            });*/
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                </div>
    <?php if($product_config['tab_full_background']):?>
            </div>
            <?php if($custom_block && $static_block_tab):?>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="custom-block-tab">
                    <?php echo $custom_block->toHtml(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Find  tabindex="-1" in your file and remove in file

Comment: Not working..by removing this

Comment: Find "<div class="data item title"" in file and add also  tabindex="-1" in this div

Comment: Still there in this div => tabindex="0". so please replace tabindex from tabindex="0" to tabindex="-1"

Comment: bad luck brother..not working

Answer (score 0):

I have used that way to disable/remove tabs.
You can disable tabs using override template file.

**Copy file from below location**

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml

**and paste it to your custom theme location.**

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[module]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml

and do change in code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                <?php
                    if($name == 'product.info.description' && 
                        $name == 'reviews.tab' && 
                        $name ==  'custom.tab'){
                        continue;
                    }
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>-title">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $html ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have to remove all code from the app/ details.phtml?

Comment: No. Just need to add if() condition in foreach loop.

Comment: It's still navigating through keyboard. Actually I'm not php or magento developer.

Comment: Did you add if condition?

Comment: Yes..now I added my default detail.phtml. You can check